# Dockerfile: adding and removing files during build: problem with RUN rm -r

Tags: dockerfile

In my Dockerfile I want to add a dir and remove some existing dirs. Add works but Remove does not.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM wordpress:5.5.1-php7.4-apache

COPY themes/twentyseventeen-b /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen-b
COPY images/header.jpg /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/a.jpg

#This is line that causes an error:
RUN rm -r /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/twentytwenty
```

-COPY works and my dirs are created and the files uploaedd

-RUN rm -r /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/twentytwenty does not work:

`rm: cannot remove '/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/twentytwenty': No such file or directory`

But I know that dir exists (if I comment out the RUN rm.... line and let the build complete I can CLI over to the container and see the dir is there).

I tried using single quotes around the dir name -- but the same problem exists.

I also tried to rm the twentyseventeen-b dir right after creation. It does not give a build error but it also does not delete the dir (I still see the dir in CLI):

```
FROM wordpress:5.5.1-php7.4-apache
COPY themes/twentyseventeen-b /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen-b
RUN rm -r /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen-b
```

If I use the CLI I can rm any dirs in /var/www/html.

The docker-compose.yml that runs this Dokerfile:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   db:
     build: ./mariadb
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     build: ./wordpress
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress

volumes:
    db_data: {}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to add `-f` argument to `rm` command which means: "ignore nonexistent files and arguments, never prompt"

for example:

```
RUN rm -rf /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/twentytwenty
```

Comment: The -f flag will keep the error from showing -- but the problem still remains... I cannot delete the dirs I need to during the container creation process.

Comment: by default in `wordpress:5.5.1-php7.4-apache` has no preinstalled themes. Try running wordpress container with cleaned db containers'`s data

Comment: The package has 2017, 2019 and 2020 dirs in the themes folder. I want to delete some of them at creation time. After the container is running I can delete with the CLI so I see they are there. But I can't with RUN rm in the Dockerfile.

Comment: looks like WordPress store themes in your database, try running WP container with empty database

Comment: It is not database related. I am trying to delete files in the filesystem /var/www/html/. I can see the files there. I can rm them using the CLI. I want to be able to rm them with a RUN command in Dockerfile.